# Multiply DF Column Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

If I have a column of numbers, how do I multiply them together?

```
val numbers = Seq((2, 7),(1, 9),(10, 0)).toDF("A", "B")
```

Answer Want

```
val ResultWant = Seq(20, 0).toDF("A", "B")
```

I noticed that there is no reduce by Key or agg(multiply) function, which is annoying.

The best method I can think of is to write out every column as an array and then use reducebyleft function to multiply everything then repackage it all together.

```
val A = numbers.select($"A").map(r => r.getInt(0)).collect
val AWant = A.reduceLeft((x,y) => x * y)
```

Is there any other more efficient way?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best method I can think of is to write out every column as an array and then use reducebyleft function to multiply everything then repackage it all together.

```
val A = numbers.select($"A").map(r => r.getInt(0)).collect
val AWant = A.reduceLeft((x,y) => x * y)
```

Is there any other more efficient way? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a schema to make your `DataFrame` into a `Dataset`, and then using `reduce()`. You can manage this with a `DataFrame`, but it's messier.

```
scala> case class rowSchema(A : Int, B : Int)
defined class rowSchema

scala> val ds = numbers.as[rowSchema]
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[rowSchema] = [A: int, B: int]

scala> val product = ds.reduce((r1, r2) => rowSchema(r1.A * r2.A, r1.B * r2.B))
product: rowSchema = rowSchema(20,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce can be used without collect:

```
val numbers = Seq((2, 7),(1, 9),(10, 0)).toDF("A", "B")
val result = numbers.select("A").reduce((acc, curr) => Row(acc.getInt(0) * curr.getInt(0)))
println(result.getInt(0))
```

Output:
20